# Is it possible to increase the video RAM on a system with Intel onboard video?

Tags: memory, graphics-card

I bought a new computer with a Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1), which has dedicated video RAM of 64MB.

**Is it possible to do something about this?** For test I downloaded a couple of games, and even old Counter Strike 1.6 is not playable on this PC.

Computer Specifications:

- **Processor** - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q9400 @ 2.66GHz
- **RAM** - 6GB
- **Video Card** - Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)
- **Dedicated Memory** - 64 MB
- **Total Memory** - 2.0 GB
- **Pixel Shader Version** - 4.0
- **Vertex Shader Version** - 4.0
- **Operating System** - Microsoft Windows 10 (build 17763), 64-bit

Comment: When you say *"new"* you mean *'about ten years old'*? You ought to be able to use a fairly modern 3rd Party GPU, the motherboard ought to be able to take it. You're not going to be able to play any vaguely recent game on that GPU.

Comment: IIRC back then you would assign a fixed amount of RAM to the GPU. It could be changed in the BIOS setup. Not that it’ll really help performance.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this... make a comment to say why? it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the question to be "Can you do something about the RAM amount on the on-board (intel) GPU."

Depending on your BIOS, you may be able to assign more RAM to the GPU, but it won't make a significant difference to the game-playing ability of the GPU, as it's simply not powerful enough. bear in mind that any RAM you do assign to the GPU is not usable to the CPU.

You can't add RAM specifically for the GPU to use.

As a way to resolve the situation, you can add a dedicated GPU to the machine, depending on the available connectivity.

Comment: Any mobo compatible with that CPU ought to be PCI, for sure.

Comment: PCI != PCIe... ;). Being serious, you could be right, but without a Mobo model, I wouldn't want to say. i'll remove the line from the answer to prevent confusion, however.

Comment: Sorry, correct. I have one machine here with the exact same CPU, Q9400 [lovely old workhorse, now put out to grass as a remote server] with a simple NVidia 210; so it's PCI-E 2.0 even at that age

Comment: Awesome. I know some companies have a (bad) habit of shipping machines without the connectors soldered on to the mobo to save on cost on low-budget machines. (I'm looking at you, Dell!). This may mean the machine has the ability but not the physical hardware. lets hope this is not the case.