# Need some knowledge about Graphic cards

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I apologize if these questions are simple and for someone stupid, but I'm with hardware on You!

I bought a new(used) computer with a Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1), which has dedicated video RAM of 64MB and only 1 VGA port.

> Already got 2 problems with it.
>
> 1. For test I downloaded a couple of games, and even old Counter Strike 1.6 is not playable on this PC.
> 2. I can't add extended monitor because of of 1 VGA port.

After couple days of researching I understand that I need to buy different (PCI ?!) graphics card?

For example: https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-210/

> Questions:
>
> 1.I will need to change existing graphic card with this one or add in some extra slot?
>
> 2.How I researched online, almost all graphic card has only 1 VGA output and maybe (HDMI or DVA), but both of my monitors have only VGA
>   input, so how can I manage to extend them? Because I bought VGA
>   splitter and it shows same display on both monitors(monitor 2,
>   replicates monitor 1).

Computer Specifications:

**Operating System**

```
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
```

**CPU**

```
Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400 @ 2.66GHz
```

**RAM**

```
6.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 332MHz (5-5-5-15)
```

**Motherboard**

```
Hewlett-Packard 3032h (XU1 PROCESSOR)
```

**Graphics**

```
Generic Non-PnP Monitor (1920x1080@60Hz)

Intel Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (HP)

Intel Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (HP)
```

**Audio**

```
C-Media PCI Audio Device
```

Comment: It's important here to highlight your previous question... as it does share similarities to this one. https://superuser.com/questions/1399281/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-video-ram-on-a-system-with-intel-onboard-video/1399286?noredirect=1#comment2110646_1399286

Comment: You don’t have a dedicated GPU, so there isn’t a GPU to replace, the iGPU also very unlikely even supports Windows 10.  The reason you couldn’t play the application in question is due to display drivers, WDDM 1.1 indicates it only supports Windows 7, not Windows 10.  Intel does not publish Windows 10 compatible display drivers.  Without display drivers you can not run the application in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. I will need to change existing graphic card with this one or add in some extra slot?**

You will need to add a card into the machine, using the appropriate slot. It's likely this slot will be a 'PCIe' slot and will look like one of the examples in this image. [[image: Pcie Slots]

[Pinched from https://networking.ringofsaturn.com/PC/slottypes.php](https://networking.ringofsaturn.com/PC/slottypes.php)

**2. How can I achieve multiple monitors**

I'm not sure where you have been researching. Most modern cards carry multiple ports of different types to allow different technology. This one : [nVidia Geforce GTX 210](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/1gb-gigabyte-g-210-1200mhz-gddr3-gpu-590mhz-shader-1405mhz-16-cores-d-sub-dual-link-dvi-i-hdmi-low-p?gclid=Cj0KCQiA1sriBRD-ARIsABYdwwH03BaNj2yXThyUDbRKLCS7ivNQaYJRS7_3KKsvAGcQKfumJdrLaAcaAojMEALw_wcB) has a VGA (15Pin Dsub), A  DVI-D and a HDMI connector.

You can connect displays to any of these and set the OS to use them as unique displays. You can also use adapters to convert HDMI to DVI-D and VGA to connect to monitors you already have.

A VGA Spiltter splits the output signal only. It does not present each screen to the computer as separate displays.